# Core data migration: app crash on updating app

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Hi I am new to `Core data` and I am working on MyApp5.0.In this I added an attribute for an entity in the current version of data model,say myModel 3.0 and the app worked well too. Now when I update from the old project version MyApp4.0 to MyApp5.0 ,where i made these changes without adding another `data model`,throws an app crash.(the current version of MyApp4.0 is myModel 4.0)

I tried to remove the `attribute` from the `entity` or the changes from data model - myModel 3.0, then add a new model version- myModel 4.0 and again add the same attribute.The app still gives a crash on updating from MyApp4.0 to MyApp5.0.
Seems like a light weight immigration won't do.Please help.

Comment: So do a full migration.  Do you have a particular problem that you need assistance with?

Comment: I only know to perform light one and have written the code for same.How can I do a full migration?

Comment: That is beyond the scope of SO.  There are many HOWTOs and tutorials available.

Comment: You will likely need to roll back to a revision (hopefully you're using git or something) where everything was working and start again from there. Then, ensure you've done your migration correctly. Add model version and then make sure you are making changes to the current model and not the new one.